# How can I change the filename timestamp?

Tags: command-line, filename, timestamp

I have dat files' names in chronological order:

```
FileName_YYYY_MM_DD_HHMM.dat
```

Is there any commands for adding 30 minutes to each timestamp?

Comment: are those timestamps same as their creation date ? is it same as `ls --full-time` ?

Comment: No, the timestamps are different as their created/modified date. The timestamps are based on the time that the data was measured.

Comment: See,  since those timestamps are custom, it's going to require a script, that has to calculate adding 30 minutes to the date, there's not gonna be any simple command. so it might take a little bit for people to respond

Comment: are there any time stamps that are close to midnight , such that adding 30 minutes may result in need to change a day by one ?

Comment: what format are hours ? 12 then 1,2,3  (12 hour format ) or 12 to 13 to 14, 15 . . . 23, 00 (24 hour format )  ?

Comment: Thank you. I've been struggling to search the solution but doesn't work. I desperately need help on this..

Comment: It's 24 hours format and it may result in changing the day/month/year by adding 30 minutes. For example, if the file has a timestamp of 2015_05_15_2330, the timestamp will need to be changed to 2015_05_16_0000.

Comment: @Serg He, where is your solution? =)

Comment: @A.B. working on it , bro. I'm not as pro as you guys are

Comment: @Serg give me a ping 

Comment: @strawberrie posted an answer. The script considers actual timestamps in filenames and 24 hour format, as well as day change. Please review

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `python` :

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import glob, re, os, datetime
os.chdir('/path/to/dir')
for f in glob.glob('*.dat'):
    ini_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(re.search(r'(?<=_)(?:\d|_)+(?=.dat$)', f).group(), '%Y_%m_%d_%H%M')
    fin_time = (ini_time + datetime.timedelta(minutes=30)).strftime('%Y_%m_%d_%H%M%S')
    os.rename(f, 'Filename_' + str(fin_time) + '.dat')
```

- `os.chdir('/path/to/dir')` will change the current directory to the directory containing the `.dat` files. Replace `/path/to/dir` with the actual path.
- `glob.glob('*.dat')` will find the files ending in `.dat`
- `ini_time` variable will at first cut out the date-time from the original file name using `re` module and then sort out which entry represents what in the string that is taken out so that we can add the required time to this
- `fin_time` will contain the resultant time i.e. `ini_time` plus 30 minutes
- `os.rename` will rename the file accordingly.

Also note that, with successive file names (differed by 30 minutes) the renamed file will overwrite the next one, hence it it is better to add the seconds to the renamed file name so that it remains safe. Otherwise you need to save the renamed files to a different directory and then replace them with the original ones later.

Comment: You and python, a great love. =) +1

Comment: You should not use the string `Filename_` in the rename method.

Comment: @A.B. Why is that ? (+1 for you too)

Comment: Do you know why I have some files missing after running the python script? The timestamp for each file has 30-min difference. Below is the output for the first few filenames:
Filename_2011_01_11_1630.dat
Filename_2011_01_11_1830.dat
Filename_2011_01_11_1900.dat
Filename_2011_01_11_2030.dat
Filename_2011_01_11_2100.dat

Comment: @strawberrie I don't know..it have tested it and working well for me without any problem..have you run the script replacing the `/path/to/file` with the full path to the directory?

Comment: I set the directory in the terminal so I deleted the /path/to/file

Comment: @strawberrie I think i have not tested with the successive data and thats the thing....the problem is that if any other file exists by the same name it will overwrite that..as we are dealing with successive file names (differed by 30 minutes) the renamed file will overwrite the next one..thats the case. i am feeling like a stupid now. i have modified the answer to add seconds to it so the filenames so will not be overwritten..if you want to stick with upto minutes solutions then you have to save the renamed files in another directory and then move them back to the source directory..

Comment: No worries. I have backed up files. Now, it works for me after you added the seconds!!! Is there anyway the timestamp be changed without the seconds? Thanks!!

Comment: I think I can probably edit that in another way. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23850/discussion-between-heemayl-and-strawberrie).

Comment: Idea: Change it so that it processes the files with the LAST creation times first. Then there won't be any conflicts.

Answer (score 2):

Using `bash`, the renamed files are in a new sub folder `renamed`.

Start the script in the folder where the files are located.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

mkdir -p renamed   

# loop over all dat files in the current folder
for f in *.dat; do

    # the filename without extension    
    filename="${f%%.*}"

    # your timestamp
    old_timestamp=$(echo $filename | grep -P "[0-9]{4}_[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{4}$")

    if [ "$old_timestamp" == "" ]; then
        >&2 echo "not a valid filename: '$f', skipped."
    else
      # a valid date from the timestamp
      new_date=$(echo "$old_timestamp" | awk -F_ '{HM=NF; D=NF-1; M=NF-2; Y=NF-3; print $Y "-" $M "-" $D " " substr($HM,1,2) ":" substr($HM,3,2) ":00"}')

      # the new time stamp, 30 mins in the future
      changed_timestamp=$(date --date "$new_date 30 minutes" "+%Y_%m_%d_%H%M")

      # copy the file, ${f##*.} is the extension
      cp "$f" renamed/"${filename/$old_timestamp/$changed_timestamp.${f##*.}}"
    fi
done
```

example output:

```bsh
% ls -og FileName*
-rw-rw-r-- 1 0 Mai 16 20:35 FileName_2015_05_16_2235.dat

% ./timestamp

% ls -og renamed/FileName*
-rw-rw-r-- 1 0 Mai 16 20:35 FileName_2015_05_16_2305.dat
```

Comment: @strawberrie the renamed files are now placed in a sub folder `renamed`

Comment: good idea to save renamed files into an extra folder. In case something goes awry, OP still has originals. Good thinking, hence +1

Comment: Thanks @A.B. I got the following error after running your script:

TimeChange.sh: 21: TimeChange.sh: Bad substitution

My actual filename or the fixed prefix before the timestamp is like FileName_123.Data_YYYY_MM_DD_HHMM.dat

Comment: Per definition, for `FileName_123.Data_YYYY_MM_DD_HHMM.dat`the part `.Data_YYYY_MM_DD_HHMM.dat` is the extension. And therefore `FileName_123` isn't a valid timestamp.

Comment: @strawberrie I have my script changed

Answer (score 1):

**SCRIPT**

This is the edited version of my original script. OP originally didn't provide full information about the naming format. This script adapts to what OP mentioned in the comments was the correct file naming.

*Technical notes: *

In this script we separate filename into 6 separate fields using awk, with underscore as field delimiter. First two fields , $1 and $2 are considered static text string. Fields 3,4,5, and 6 are the timestamp at which OP's data was sampled, *not* the file's creation date on the filesystem.

Variable COPYDIR holds name of new directory where files with updated timestamp will go. We create that directory in current working directory with `mkdir $COPYDIR`

Variables TEXTSTRING and DATESTRING hold static text and timestamp respectivelly. In the sample output bellow I have used two different strings to prove that script will work regardless of what text the first two fields hold.

NEWEPOCHTIME is variable that holds calculated new timestamp in unix epoch format. NEWDATE is variable that holds converted timestamp from unix epoch to YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM format. NEWAPPEND is the actual timestamp that will be added to the file in OP's desired YYYY_MM_DD_HHMM format.

`cp $file "$COPYDIR"/"%TEXTSTRING""$NEWAPPEND".dat` copies the old file into "converted_files" directory ( instead of moving, to prevent data loss) with the updated datastamp.

*Notice*, the script will work as long as the naming format is *really* followed, i.e., all the files are *really* have `SomeText_123.Data_YYYY_MM_DD_HHMM.dat` format.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#
# Author: Serg Kolo
# Description: this script takes timestamp within the filename
# (which may be different from file's actual creation date)
# converts that date and time to unix's epoch time
# adds 30 minutes to it and renames it

COPYDIR="converted_files"
mkdir $COPYDIR

for file in *.dat; do
        TEXTSTRING=$(stat -c %n $file | awk -F'_' '{print $1"_"$2"_"}' )
        DATESTRING=$( stat -c %n $file | awk -F'_' '{gsub(".dat","");  print $3"-"$4"-"$5" "$6}' )
        NEWEPOCHTIME=$( expr $( date --date="$DATESTRING" +%s ) + 1800 )
        NEWDATE=$(date --date=@"$NEWEPOCHTIME" +%F"_"%R)
        NEWAPPEND=$(echo $NEWDATE | awk '{gsub("-","_");gsub(":","");print}')
        cp $file "$COPYDIR"/"$TEXTSTRING""$NEWAPPEND".dat
done
```

**SCRIPT IN ACTION**

The demonstration bellow is direct copy from my terminal. Notice that I've created original files with two different strings in the first two fields. So this script should work no matter what is in the beginning of the filename, as long as there are really only two strings separated by underscore

The script was named `notes-conversion` because I developed the script from the notes I took while working on this question.

Notice that filenames which have HHMM part as 2345 (which is 15 minutes before midnight) get updated to 0015, and DD part is updated to next day. 24 hour format preserved.

In addition, because for loop only looks for `.dat` files, we avoid renaming other files or directories that may happen to be in the working directory, thus avoiding any potential data loss. In the example bellow, original directory holds 11 items, 3 of which are `*.txt` files for testing, so we only work with 8 `.dat` files. In the directory where updated files go, we see 8 files, all `.dat` and no other files. Data is safe, script does its job.

```
[68 ]SERGIY@UBUNTU_[/home/xieerqi/testdir/conversion/convert2]
***********************************************
85 $ ls
FileName_123.Dat_2015_05_31_1245.dat  Test.txt
FileName_123.Dat_2015_05_31_2345.dat  YoloSwag_123.Dat_2015_05_31_1245.dat
FileName_Foo.Bar_2015_05_31_1245.dat  YoloSwag_123.Dat_2015_05_31_2345.dat
FileName_Foo.Bar_2015_05_31_2345.dat  YoloSwag_Foo.Bar_2015_05_31_1245.dat
File.txt                              YoloSwag_Foo.Bar_2015_05_31_2345.dat
Random.txt

[68 ]SERGIY@UBUNTU_[/home/xieerqi/testdir/conversion/convert2]
***********************************************
86 $ ls | wc -l
11

[68 ]SERGIY@UBUNTU_[/home/xieerqi/testdir/conversion/convert2]
***********************************************
87 $ notes-conversion                                                                                

[68 ]SERGIY@UBUNTU_[/home/xieerqi/testdir/conversion/convert2]
***********************************************
88 $ ls converted_files/; ls converted_files/ | wc -l                                                
FileName_123.Dat_2015_05_31_1315.dat  YoloSwag_123.Dat_2015_05_31_1315.dat
FileName_123.Dat_2015_06_01_0015.dat  YoloSwag_123.Dat_2015_06_01_0015.dat
FileName_Foo.Bar_2015_05_31_1315.dat  YoloSwag_Foo.Bar_2015_05_31_1315.dat
FileName_Foo.Bar_2015_06_01_0015.dat  YoloSwag_Foo.Bar_2015_06_01_0015.dat
8

[67 ]SERGIY@UBUNTU_[/home/xieerqi/testdir/conversion/convert2]
***********************************************
89 $
```

**EXPLANATION (from original post)**

*) Today I've learned that Unix-Linux systems count time in [Epoch time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), or simply put seconds.

*) the script takes each file name, extracts date, converts it to epoch , adds 1800 seconds (which is exactly 30 minutes), and saves the file with than new timestamp.

*) This script addresses what OP wanted - change timestamp in filename, not update creation time of the file itself

**Tools used:**

- ubuntu 15.04
- GNU bash 4.3.30
- GNU awk 4.1.1
- date (GNU coreutils) 8.23

Comment: by the way, ls | wc -l before gives 36 files, and after script also 36 files, none missing

Comment: Also, reason why i use stat -c %n file, is because parsing output of ls is not a good idea, generally. Some folks use `find` command, which is also good.

Comment: Thanks @Serg. I don't know why I only left 2 out of 727 files left in the folder after running your script...

Comment: Was there any difference between the actual file names and the example you posted ?

Comment: also, did you run the first line in the "Script in action"  ? the rm * was for cleaning up my own directory and then creating bunch of test files with different dates in file names. You were not supposed to run that

Comment: are they all really following same format ?   FileName_YYYY_MM_DD_HHMM.dat  ?

Comment: @FatMind yes, OP wants the day to also change. Which part this filename comes from ? before I ran the script or after ?

Comment: @strawberrie did you make any adjustments to the script or did you run it as is ? awk there searches for files with FileName string in them. Files without that string may disappear. try removing /FileName/ part if there is no other files in that folder

Comment: Sorry for any mixup. My actual filename looks somewhat like this: FileName_123.Data_YYYY_MM_DD_HHMM.dat. I ran both your original script and another one with the adjusted FileName..Thanks a bunch for your help tho!

Comment: @strawberrie I've updated the script. Now it should work as  long as the actual filename is preserved and really followed. I suggest you add that information to your original question, as this really messes up a lot of those who try to answer.  For the future, please provide full information in the question; help us to help you =)

Answer (score -1):

You may use this code to do what you need assuming

1. **you should take backup and test the code first to see if it's suitable for your case**
2. you are using 24H format
3. no files will be named after 23:29 (if you
   have files after that time the code should be modified to change the date also )

**the code is :**

```
cd /path/to/the/files

for i in `ls`; do MM=${i:(-6): -4}; HH=${i: -8 : -6 }; NAME=${i: 0 : -8 } ; if [ "$MM" -lt 30 ] ; then  NEWMM=$((10#$MM+30)); mv -f $i $NAME$HH$NEWMM.dat ; else NEWHH=$((10#$HH+1));NEWMM=$((10#$MM-30)) ; mv -f $i $NAME$NEWHH$NEWMM.dat ; fi ; done ;
```

**How it works:** 
The code will check the minutes part in the file name  `MM` then if it's less than 30 it will add 30 to the `MM` if it equals 30 or more it will add 1 hour to the `HH` part in the name and deduct 30 minutes from the `MM` part of the name

Comment: for down voter please notify the reason ?